# How to add persistence to a image field dynamically

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I have created an image uploader using UI component form in Magento 2 but I also want to fill data from DB dynamically using JS to the image uploader when someone edits the form.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

your add / edit form should have a data provider attached to it. Your data provider should return an array that should contain a field called the same as your field that holds the path to the image and a few other details

Something like this:

```
$data['field'] = [
                    0 => [
                        'name' => 'filename goes here',
                        'url' => 'url to image goes here',
                        'size' => 'image size goes here',
                        'type' => 'image mime goes here. try with  "image"'
                    ]
                ];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use Data provider. I have to set the values using JS/Knockout to the field dynamically. Can you please help?